# Error 1004 when pulling table with ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a quick way to pull financial statements (a basic table) from yahoo finance (e.g. https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/financials?p=FB) with VBA.
I'm a complete noob so I used the record macro tool and Get data from web and tried (with my non-existent VBA knowledge) to adapt it to use a variable (Ticker) to change the company.

When using the get data from web function the table is imported perfectly but it doesn't work with VBA code. I get 1004 error about either ListObject.DisplayName or Refresh BackgroundQuery

```
Sub Macro5()
Dim Ticker As String
Ticker = InputBox("Ticker")
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table" & Ticker, Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/& Ticker &/financials?p=&Ticker &""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data2 = Source{2}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Type modifié"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data2,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Type modifié"""
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table & Ticker")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table" & Ticker
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

The idea is to output the Income Statement form for the "Ticker" (FB in my exemple).
I'm using Excel 365 on windows

Thanks a lot

Comment: were you after all tables or a specific table?

Comment: @TheSleepyGhost   I am glad that my efforts are of interest to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy method is to grab all the table elements on the page and loop those using clipboard to copy paste to sheet. You can adapt to write to different sheets based on ticker value. Use a loop over tickers to retrieve data but ensuring you create the ie object before the loop and then have the navigate2 within the loop so as to visit each new ticker page.

```
Public Sub GetTables()
    Dim clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet, j As Long, tables As Object
    Dim ie As Object, ticker As String
    ticker = "FB"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Cells.UnMerge
    ws.Cells.ClearContents
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/financials?p=" & ticker

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set tables = .document.querySelectorAll("table")

        For j = 0 To tables.Length - 1
            clipboard.SetText tables.item(j).outerHTML
            clipboard.PutInClipboard
            ws.Cells(LastRow(ws) + 2, 1).PasteSpecial
        Next
        .Quit
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Public Function LastRow(ByVal sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

---

This second method is rather a leap in knowledge for you, but maybe useful in future and to other readers. You can extract all the info on the page from a script tag. With some string splitting on the innerHTML of that script element you can get a string which a json parser can handle. You can then parse the json for whatever info you want. I include an outline only below.

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
' Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'Download and add in jsonconverter.bas from https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas
Public Sub GetYahooData()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, ticker As String
    ticker = "FB"
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/financials?p=" & ticker

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim script As Object, scripts As Object, i As Long, extract As String, json As Object
        Set scripts = .document.querySelectorAll("script")

        For i = 0 To scripts.Length - 1
            If InStr(1, scripts.item(i).innerHTML, "/* -- Data -- */") Then
                Set script = scripts.item(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not script Is Nothing Then
            extract = Split(Split(script.innerHTML, "root.App.main = ")(1), "(this));")(0)
            extract = Left$(extract, InStrRev(extract, ";") - 1)
            Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(extract)("context")("dispatcher")("stores")("QuoteSummaryStore")("cashflowStatementHistory")
        End If
        If Not json Is Nothing Then
            'parse json for data of interest
        End If
        Stop ' <== Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

There is simply too much info in the json to go through it all but here is a snapshot extract of the webpage on the left, and the json which relates to it on the right:

[image]

---

Comment: I can't upvote so I'll use this to thank you. I'll use the remainder of the year to understand what's going on in that code, but again thanks a lot for the input !

Comment: I am always happy to go through stuff as and when you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to workout solution on your adopted code. Your table of interest is `Table 2` on the page when we retrieve the URL through Excel Data Tab from web. We have to tackle two problems .

- Table reference is proper. As we run the program number of times query table name is in Excel memory and is not removed even after deleting the sheet. So I have to increment table index like `[Table 2 (2)]` then next time `[Table 2 (3)]` at 3 places in the code. If we increment table index every time program will run correctly.To find out what is the index number of table `ListTables()` sub routine will help. I could not find a suitable way that Excel do not remember table index of a deleted sheet table.
- Second necessary point is to close connection. I have added suitable code for the same.
  Final code works out as following.

  ```
   Sub Macro7()
   '
   ' Macro1 Macro
   '

   '
  Dim Cn As Variant
  Dim Ticker As String

  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Ticker = InputBox("Ticker")

  ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 2 (18)", Formula:= _
      "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & Ticker & "/financials?p=" & Ticker & """))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data2 = Source{2}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data2,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
  With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
      "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 2 (2)"";Extended Properties=""""" _
      , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
      .CommandType = xlCmdSql
      .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 2 (18)]")
      .RowNumbers = False
      .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
      .PreserveFormatting = True
      .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
      .BackgroundQuery = True
      .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
      .SavePassword = False
      .SaveData = True
      .AdjustColumnWidth = True
      .RefreshPeriod = 0
      .PreserveColumnInfo = True
      .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_2__18"
      .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With
  'Range("A16").Select
  For Each Cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
      Cn.Delete
   Next Cn
  For Each Cn In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
      Cn.Delete
  Next Cn

  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True


  End Sub
  ```

  And code routine for listing table index is:

  ```
  Sub ListTables()
      Dim xTable As ListObject
      Dim xSheet As Worksheet
      Dim I As Long
      I = -1
      Sheets.Add.Name = "Table Name"
      For Each xSheet In Worksheets
      For Each xTable In xSheet.ListObjects
      I = I + 1
      Sheets("Table Name").Range("A1").Offset(I).Value = xTable.Name
      Sheets("Table Name").Range("B1").Offset(I).Value = xSheet.Name
      Next xTable
      Next
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! Hopefully I'll understand it someday !